# Переопределенный метод toString() возвращает hashCode

Tags: java, строки

Проблема состоит в том, что при попытке переопределения `List`, запрос все равно возвращает `hashCode`. Позвольте объяснить.

У меня есть дочерний класс `ContactWrapper`, который имеет такие атрибуты как: `contactType` и `contact`.
Родительский класс `PersonResponceWrapper`, помимо своих атрибутов, имеет поле `List<ContactWrapper>`.

Проблем не возникает, если персона имеет всего один контакт. Элементарное переопределение `toString()` в дочернем классе возвращает нам читабельный вид типа: "Phone: 8(800)-555-35-35". Но если контактов несколько, необходимо переопределять `toString()` в родительском классе, и вот здесь кроется проблема.

Я пытался решить это таким образом:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    List<ContactWrapper> contactList = getContacts();
    String string = "";
    for (ContactWrapper contact:contactList) {
        string = contact.getContactType() + ": " + contact.getContact + "; ";
    }
    return string;
}
```

Это метод, который записывает БД в `csv` файл:

```
public byte[] generateReport() throws IOException {
    File targetFile = new File(FILE_NAME);
    try {
        Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(targetFile.toPath());

        StatefulBeanToCsv<PersonResponseWrapper> csvWriter = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<PersonResponseWrapper>(writer)
                .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
                .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                .withEscapechar(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER)
                .withLineEnd(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END)
                .withOrderedResults(false)
                .build();

        List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) personRepository.findAll();

        csvWriter.write(personList.stream().map(PersonResponseWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        writer.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] result = Files.readAllBytes(targetFile.toPath());
    targetFile.delete();
    return result;
}
```

Конструктор `PersonResponceWrapper`:

```
public PersonResponseWrapper(Person person) {
    this.id = person.getId();
    this.name = person.getName();
    this.surname = person.getSurname();
    this.patronymic = person.getPatronymic();
    this.birthDate = person.getBirthDate();
    if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(person.getContacts())) {
        contacts = person.getContacts().stream().map(v -> new ContactWrapper(v.getId(),
                                                  v.getContactType(), v.getContact())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Вот такой вывод я получаю, вне зависимости, переопределен метод `toString()` в родительском классе, или нет:

[image]

Элементарное переопределение в дочернем классе `ContactWrapper` работает, но не в случае, когда контактов больше чем один:

[image]

---

*Всем спасибо за оказанное внимание.*

Comment: Вы в цикле переопределяете переменную `string`, а не дополняете её. От этого все проблемы

Comment: @ArchDemon добрый вечер, простите за прямоту, что Вы этим хотите сказать?

Comment: @НикитаЦарев, вам надо не `string =` писать, но `string +=`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб благодарю за разъяснение, но, к сожалению, это не помогло. Да и в целом, если бы значение string не дополнялось, запрос как миниму возвращал мне пустую строку, а не `hashCode`

Comment: Что странно, какое либо переопределение метода, вообще не влияет на вывод. Может дело в самом методы записи csv файла?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `collect(Collectors.joining("-", "{", "}"));`

Comment: `toString` который приложен к вопросу - это из родительского класса  `PersonResponceWrapper`?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко, да, из родительского.

Comment: Я могу прикрепить к вопросу конструктор `PersonResponceWrapper`, может получиться прояснить что либо

Comment: Что такое `contact.getContact` (без скобочек)? Вы пишете "toString возвращает hashCode", что это значит, можете привести пример вывода значения toString в консоль? (Добавьте детали в сам вопрос.)

Comment: @Vadik в `contact.getContact` опечатался (писал руками). Сейчас прикреплю вывод.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению, не помогло. Спасибо за подсказку:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем класс `PrintReport`, в котором конструктор принимает сущность `Person`, за исключением `List<Contact>`. Вместо этого мы присваиваем атрибуту `String contact` значения `contactType` и `contact` циклом:

```
public class PrintReport {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String patronymic;
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String contacts = "";

    public PrintReport() {
    }

    public PrintReport(Person person) {
        this.id = person.getId();
        this.name = person.getName();
        this.surname = person.getSurname();
        this.patronymic = person.getPatronymic();
        this.birthDate = person.getBirthDate();
        for (Contact contact:person.getContacts()) {
            this.contacts += contact.getContactType() + ": " + contact.getContact() + "; ";
        }
    }
}
```

Затем заменяем `PersonResponceWrapper` на `PrintReport` в методе записи `csv` файла `generateReport()`:

```
public byte[] generateReport() throws IOException {
    File targetFile = new File(FILE_NAME);
    try {
        Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(targetFile.toPath());

        StatefulBeanToCsv<PrintReport> csvWriter = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<PrintReport>(writer)
                .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
                .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                .withEscapechar(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER)
                .withLineEnd(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END)
                .withOrderedResults(false)
                .build();

        List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) personRepository.findAll();

        csvWriter.write(personList.stream().map(PrintReport::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        writer.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] result = Files.readAllBytes(targetFile.toPath());
    targetFile.delete();
    return result;
}
```

---

В конечном счете, метод `toString()` переопределять не пришлось.
Всем большое спасибо за обсуждение и участие!:)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать вот так:

```
contacts = person.getContacts().stream().map(ContactWrapper::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

а сам ContactWrapper cделать через конструктор на основе Contact типа:

```
    public ContactWrapper(Contact contact) {
        this.id = contact.getId();
        this.contact = contact.getContact();
        this.contactType = contact.getContactType();
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, без изменений.